# How to round up decimal places?

Tags: php, rounding

I have below number

```
12.81 -> 12.90
12.70 -> 12.70
12.65 -> 12.70
```

In short after second decimal it should be round up the decimal values.

**.81 -> .89 should become .90.** Else as it is.

I already tried

```
echo round(12.81, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

`ceil` seems not going to work here.

Comment: Times 10, ceil, devide by 10.

Comment: `ceil(12.81*10)/10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this here:

```
echo ceil(12.81 * 10) / 10;
```